# HttpModule not called in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, httpmodule

Just spent a lot of time sifting through contradictory advice on this problem, and thought I'd post my solution.

My environment is .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012, working on an MVC 4 application. I created an Http Module like I'd done in the past, and added it to Web.config like so:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <httpModules>
   <add name="MyModule" type="Services.MyModule, Services" />
  </httpModules>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, the application never called the module's Init(). Eventually, I found advice that the modules should instead be inside `<system.webServer>`, and the element named `<modules>` instead of `<httpModules>`, like so:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules>
   <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule" type="Services.MyModule, Services" />
  </modules>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Re-ran the application, and it called Init() as expected. FWIW, the page with the direction is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

HTH

Comment: You should split your question in 2 parts: one question and your answer

Comment: You cannot have TWO 'types' in the <add line. That's syntactically incorrect and would not compile. I am surprised this even worked

Answer (score 26):

`<system.web>` is for IIS 6 and below (including Cassini), `<system.webServer>` is for IIS 7 and above.  I generally put in both -- just in case -- and then add this node to `<system.webServer>` so it doesn't barf on the redundancy:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Comment: that is a great one liner!